# Selecting Network Interface in SFML

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, sfml

How is it possible to select which network interface to use?
I have multiple VPNs installed, Hamachi for example (25.0.0.0)
It is the first one in priority list in my "network adapters" window on Win7.
However, when I use sockets in SFML, it still uses my "local interface", which is 192.168.etc.etc.

Some games I saw are always using local interface, some of them are using the first one in priority list, some of them allow player/user to choose which one to use.

How is it handled in SFML?
I looked through documentation, but haven't found anything about it.
Google did not help too, probably because I don't know how to phrase my question properly.

Comment: Usually by using `bind`.

Comment: Oh, now I realize I can select an IP too, not only port with "bind". Should I use IP of my PC in that network? Or there is a way to retrieve list of available interfaces or something.

Comment: AFAIK SFML doesn't provide the ability to get a list of interfaces so you'll likely need to add some platform specific code to your project to handle it.